# split traffic on two eth ports

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, traffic-shaping, proxmox

I have a linux [Proxmox](http://proxmox.com) server with two ethernet ports. The problem is that I have two uplinks that I would like to use with different bandwidth limitations. The first uplink maxes out at 100mbs and the other maxes out at 10mbps. Is it possible to have both uplinks plugged into my server and split incoming/outgoing traffic on these ports?

Answer (score 0):

For outgoing, you can set a multipath route using the `ip` command. See http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html. There is no simple way to balance the incoming traffic.